# Python Extracting rows not in another numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Given two numpy matrices 'a' and 'b', I am trying to extract rows in 'a' that are not in 'b'. The problem is the dimension of 'b' is not fixed. If I use `.tolist()`, then it does not work when 'b' has dimension = 1, since it considers each row with individual elements of 'b' instead of the entire 'b' array.

Here are results of some functions that I tried:
[image: Link to the image]

In the image, the first and last result is correct. If 'b' is a matrix, then converting to list works, but if it is an array, then `.all().any()` works.

`np.isin()` also does not work since 'a' is multi-dimensional.

What is a general way to achieve this?

Comment: `c` is of shape `(1,)` not `(1, 3)`. Did you notice that?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I meant to say, `c` is of shape `(3, )` not `(1, 3)`

Comment: Yes. I had and from there I concluded why `.tolist()` does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.isin` actually works and the correct way to do is like this:

```
>>> a = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3,3)
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> b
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> c = np.arange(1, 4).reshape(1, 3)
>>> c
array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

Then elements in `a` not in `b` are:

```
>>> a[~np.isin(a,b)].reshape(-1, a.shape[1])
array([[7, 8, 9]])
```

Elements in `a` not in `c` are (assuming the no. of columns are same in both matrices):

```py
>>> a[~np.isin(a,c)].reshape(-1, a.shape[1])
array([[4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed trying this one. Thanks a lot,

Comment: It does not work if elements are same in the rows, but nevertheless thanks. It helped a lot.